# How to determine if a job is failed

Tags: kubernetes

How can I programatically determine if a `job` has failed for good and will not retry any more? I've seen the following on failed jobs:

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: 2018-04-25T22:38:34Z
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-04-25T22:38:34Z
    message: Job has reach the specified backoff limit
    reason: BackoffLimitExceeded
    status: "True"
    type: Failed
```

However, the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-patterns) doesn't explain why `conditions` is a list. Can there be multiple conditions? If so, which one do I rely on? Is it a guarantee that there will only be one with `status: "True"`?

Answer (score 3):

`JobConditions` is similar as `PodConditions`. You may read about `PodConditions` in [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/).

Anyway, To determine a successful pod, I follow another way. Let's look at it.

---

**There are two fields in Job Spec.**

One is [`spec.completion`](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/batch/v1/types.go#L78) (default value 1), which says,

> Specifies the desired number of successfully finished pods the
>   job should be run with.

Another is [`spec.backoffLimit`](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/batch/v1/types.go#L88) (default value 6), which says,

> Specifies the number of retries before marking this job failed.

---

**Now In JobStatus**

There are two fields in JobStatus too. [`Succeeded`](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/batch/v1/types.go#L146) and [`Failed`](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/batch/v1/types.go#L150). `Succeeded` means how many times the Pod completed successfully and `Failed` denotes, The number of pods which reached phase Failed.

- Once the `Success` is equal or bigger than the `spec.completion`, the job will become `completed`.
- Once the `Failed` is equal or bigger than the `spec.backOffLimit`, the job will become `failed`.

So, the logic will be here,

```
if job.Status.Succeeded >= *job.Spec.Completion {
    return "completed"
} else if job.Status.Failed >= *job.Spec.BackoffLimit {
    return "failed"
}
```

Comment: I can't _just_ check `backoffLimit`, as a job could also be failed if it runs for `activeDeadlineSeconds`, so I'd at least have to compute the runtime (I don't think that is readily available in a field). Then there's the question of whether there are _other_ reasons a job could be marked failed. `conditions` seems like the way to go, yet even after reading the pod condition docs I'm still unclear on how to interpret multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

> If so, which one do I rely on?

You might not have to choose, considering [commit dd84bba64](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/dd84bba64c8b44887bbe0fb0d72d4b820c062ea5)

> When a job is complete, the controller will indefinitely update its conditions
>   with a Complete condition.
>   This change makes the controller exit the
>   reconcilation as soon as the job is already found to be marked as complete.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. However, I already know I can determine a job is complete if `succeeded==job.spec.completion`. What I don't know is how to determine if it is failed.

Answer (score 0):

As https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.26/#jobstatus-v1-batch says:

> The latest available observations of an object's current state. When a
> Job fails, one of the conditions will have type "Failed" and status
> true. When a Job is suspended, one of the conditions will have type
> "Suspended" and status true; when the Job is resumed, the status of
> this condition will become false. When a Job is completed, one of the
> conditions will have type "Complete" and status true. More info:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/